# Count instances of a single process in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Suppose I have a program called PDF Xchange (like Adobe PDF) which opens separate windows for each documents. However there is still only 1 process PDFXEdit.exe in task manager.

How do I count the number of currently opened documents ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of windows? `WinGet, winList, ahk_exe PDFXEdit.exe` ... see [WinGet docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm)

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked ! Why don't you promote your comment to an answer I will mark it as solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just count the number of windows? WinGet, winList, ahk_exe PDFXEdit.exe ... see WinGet docs – MCL

Best answered by MCL